# Cannot read property `registry` bower

Tags: bower

I have an internal bower registry.
My `.bowerrc` looks like this:

```
{
  "resolvers": [
    "bower-art-resolver"
  ],
  "registry": //internal registry address
}
```

When I try to run `bower install` I get:

```
bower [31merror        [39m Cannot read property 'registry' of undefined
[33m
Stack trace:
[39mTypeError: Cannot read property 'registry' of undefined
    at Function.ArtifactoryResolver.extractArtifactoryRegistry
```

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 0):

After Artifactory upgrade (version 4.8.0) I faced the same problem, and reinstalling bower-art-resolver with npm solved the problem.